# Create a terrain with Blender for XNA

Tags: c#, model, xna, blender

I have been poking around online about creating height maps for terrain and I really can't get the hang of it, my question is, if I create a terrain model in blender would I be able to use that in XNA, `(VS2010)` as my terrain?

Are there any drawbacks from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

`Xna` support `.FBX` model so you can export your model from blender and use in `Xna`.

1. [using-blender-models-in-xna](http://karnbianco.co.uk/blog/2009/05/06/using-blender-models-in-xna/)
2. [Blender-toXNA](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Blender-toXNA)

but using a model that used for terrain is not good at all,as you know in each frame game engine render each object in your your camera view so if you have a large terrain it must rendered and it is not good.

so Using a model for the terrain is probably a bad idea unless the terrain is just one big square plane. You're probably going to have better luck building your terrain in code no matter what you intend the terrain to look like.you can split your terrain to small part like 512 unit.

**Edited**

[An example of terrain in xna](http://xnaterrain.codeplex.com/)

[A complete guide](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_terrain.html)

Comment: i have been looking for terrain guides for xna 4.0 but none of them are clear cut, any help?

Comment: iv looked over that  guide and i dont think i understand how its done :(

Comment: Maybe the Terrain tutorials at riemers.net can help? [Series 1](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php) [Series 4](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series4.php) (navigation is on the right; I was not able to find it at first). I have not done part 4 myself, maybe it requires part 2 and 3 (non-terrain). In part 1 he creates a terrain from a heightsmap-image where each grayscale represents a height.